# SQL Server MERGE, access to source table after OUTPUT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a copy functionality in my application. I have campaigns, and campaign packages, stored in different tables.

I have a table for outputs, and several variables:

```
DECLARE @NewIds TABLE (NewCampaignId int, NewCampaignPackageId int, OriginalCampaignId int, OriginalCampaignPackageId int)
DECLARE @NewCampaignId [int]
DECLARE @NewCampaignPackageId [int]
```

To copy the campaign, I do a MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO Campaign AS CNew USING
(SELECT * FROM Campaign WHERE Id = @CampaignId) AS COld ON 0 = 1 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (Status, Country, Culture, Title, DateFrom, DateTo, SalesRepEmail, SalesAgronomistEmail, TermsAndConditions, SalesForceCampaignId, CampaignType, Description, CampaignExpiredTitle, CampaignExpiredMessage, CampaignExpiredCTAText, CampaignExpiredCTALink)
  VALUES (Status, Country, Culture, 'Copy of ' + Title, DateFrom, DateTo, SalesRepEmail, SalesAgronomistEmail, TermsAndConditions, null, CampaignType, Description, CampaignExpiredTitle, CampaignExpiredMessage, CampaignExpiredCTAText, CampaignExpiredCTALink)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, 0, @CampaignId, 0 INTO @NewIds;
SELECT @NewCampaignId = NewCampaignId FROM @NewIds WHERE OriginalCampaignId = @CampaignId
```

This works. However, I need to update the campaign package table. For it to work, I need to preserve the original CampaignPackageId. I use merge like so

```
MERGE INTO CampaignPackage AS CPackageNew USING
(SELECT * FROM CampaignPackage WHERE Id = @CampaignId) AS CPackageOld ON 0 = 1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT(CampaignId, CanEditQuantity, Benefits, Description, Name)
VALUES(@NewCampaignId, CanEditQuantity, Benefits, Description, Name)
OUTPUT 0, inserted.Id, @CampaignId, CPackageOld.Id INTO @NewIds;
SELECT @NewCampaignPackageId = NewCampaignPackageId FROM @NewIds WHERE OriginalCampaignPackageId = CPackageOld.Id AND OriginalCampaignId = @CampaignId
```

This is where the problem is - in the last line I'm trying to assign the NewCampaignPackageId based on my outputs table, but here I have no access to `CPackageOld.Id`. I need this old id, to make sure I'm hitting the correct record in the table.

Is there any way to still have access to this variable, after OUTPUT?

Comment: What do you mean "still have access to the variable"? A variable continues to persist until the batch ends, so you *do* still have access to the variable in the above.

Comment: In the `OUTPUT` clause, you set `OriginalCampaignPackageId` in `@newIds` equal to `CPackageOld.Id`. How, then, do you expect the `WHERE` condition `OriginalCampaignPackageId = CPackageOld.Id` to even be required? You just set one equal to the other. (And if there are in fact multiple rows inserted into `@newIds`, you have more than just one problem in trying to set a scalar variable afterwards)

Comment: @Larnu I don't. In that last SELECT I'm getting "The multi-part identifier... cannot be bound"

Comment: That error has *nothing* to do with variables... You've *hidden* the important parts of the error, which isn't helpful, but I assume it's about the column `CPackageOld.Id`; there is no object/alias `CPackageOld` in your `FROM`. The only thing references in your `FROM` is `@NewIDs`, so perhaps you need to `JOIN` to the `CPackageOld` table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hm, there may be more problems. One campaign can have more packages. I need this NewCampaignPackageId later in the code (there are several more tables, I simplified it for this question). There can be more rows, so for each newly inserted row, I need to know what was it copied from, so I can fill these other tables accordingly

Comment: To clarify, maybe what I need is not clear enough :)
I did it at first with INSERT statements, several of them, and at the end of each I would assign to this "newId" a SCOPE_IDENTITY(). 

This works sometimes, but as this identity is not really dependable, sometimes I would get weird results. So I need to make sure to have the exact id of the actual row, so I went with OUTPUT. However, in later tables I'm adding more rows with these new ids, and in order to get the proper one, I want to match it with the original. This is why I need to chose from newIds based on the original id.

Comment: There is no variable `@CampaignId` in your code except where you are referencing it in a query.

Comment: @Stu there is, it's a parameter I pass to the sp, just didn't include it here

Comment: Then how are we supposed to know that's not an issue?

Comment: Because it's creating the table, it's getting proper data based on that id. I am not going to paste the entire stored procedure (nor the be code that calls it), just the parts that are not working. The passed @campaignId works.

Comment: The only problem the procedure has is that "The multi-part identifier CPackageOld.id cannot be bound", and my question relates to how to capture it (CPackageOld.id) AFTER the OUTPUT clause. It has nothing to do with @campaignId